# How to Test an Apex Trigger Which Sends Email?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I am having an issue writing a test class for my apex trigger. MY trigger works perfectly, but I don't know how to write a test class. I am new to Salesforce developing.

Here is my trigger's code:

```
trigger SFieldUpdate on Opportunity (after update) {
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>(); //master list that will hold all the emails that we send out
    for(Opportunity newOpp: Trigger.new ){ //for every new opp is created
        if(newOpp.IsWon == true){ //checks to see if the opportuinty is "closeed won" = true
            Opportunity  oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(newOpp.Id); //retrieving the old values from the opportunity
            if(newOpp.Web_Sources__c != oldOpp.Web_Sources__c){ //compares the new values to the old value of the field, if the the new value is not = to the oldval, then the fields have been updated

                //boilerplate code for the messaging object
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); //messaging object in use


                    List<String> sendTo = new List<String>(); //list that will have the email contacts

                    sendTo.add('agautam@metroexhibits.com');

                    //sendTo.add(newOpp.OwnerId);


                    mail.setToAddresses(sendTo); //calling the messaging object to take the email contacts in the parameter

                    //mail.setReplyTo('agautam@metroexhibits.com');
                    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Administrator');


                    //the body of the email

                    mail.setSubject(newOpp.Account + '-- HAS COMPLETED THE SURVEY');
                    String body = 'Your client' + ', ';
                    body+= '' + newOpp.Account + ', finished filling out the customer satisfaction survey';
                    body+= '' + ' Please see the Opportunity here, ' + newOpp.AccountId;

                    /*
                    EmailTemplate et = [Select id from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName=: 'SurveyComplete'];
                    mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(newOpp.OwnerId);
                    */
                    mail.setHtmlBody(body);

                    mails.add(mail);
                    //mail.saveAsActivity = false;

                    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);

            }

        }        

    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't even know where to start, you should be completing **Trailhead** modules, not asking questions on this forum. There's even a unit for **[Testing Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really work your way through some Trailhead modules before asking questions here if you don't know where to start and can't even share an attempt. Here is the unit on **[Testing Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers)**. As you develop any `Apex Trigger`, you should look at One Trigger Per Object and Logic-less Triggers (both of which are covered in **[Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)**). This is even more important than understanding how to test them, as it will help you build stable, robust systems that can scale.

Note that you really shouldn't use `Apex` for this functionality at all, as you can achieve everything you wish using a `Workflow Rule Email Alert` and an `Email Template`. Regardless, if you're really committed to `Apex`, here are some tips on how to test your code.

---

The basic premise of testing an `Apex Trigger` is that you must `insert`/`update`/`delete`/`undelete` records in order to get the trigger to fire. For example:

```
static testMethod void basicTriggerSmokeTest()
{
    Opportunity record = new Opportunity(/*required fields*/);
    insert record;

    Test.startTest();
        update record; // this call fires your after update trigger
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

---

The above will give you very minimal coverage. First of all, the record has `IsWon` as `false`. Second, its `Web_Sources__c` value didn't change. It does have some value, though, it just needs an assertion to verify no emails were sent in this case.

```
static testMethod void basicTriggerUnitTest_NotWonNotChanged()
{
    Opportunity record = new Opportunity(/*required fields*/);
    insert record;

    Test.startTest();
        update record;
        Integer emailInvocations = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(0, emailInvocations, 'No emails should be sent');
    // every test you write should contain meaningful assertions
}
```

---

Now at least you're verifying the trigger's behavior. But you still need to test a positive case.

```
static testMethod void basicTriggerUnitTest_IsWonIsChanged()
{
    OpportunityStage isWonStage = [
        SELECT ApiName FROM OpportunityStage WHERE IsWon = true LIMIT 1
    ];
    Opportunity record = new Opportunity(/*required fields*/);
    record.Web_Sources__c = 'A';
    record.StageName = isWonStage;
    insert record;

    record.Web_Sources__c = 'B';
    Test.startTest();
        update record;
        Integer emailInvocations = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, emailInvocations, 'An email should be sent');
}
```

---

That should get you full coverage, but it's still a long way from your work being done. You need to do bulk testing to verify that your code will work if you get a bulk update of 200 records that all match your criteria. In this case, what you care about is that you will not exceed the limit on email invocations, so you can simply create one more `Opportunity` than the limit.

```
static testMethod void bulkTriggerUnitTest_IsWonIsChanged()
{
    OpportunityStage isWonStage = [
        SELECT ApiName FROM OpportunityStage WHERE IsWon = true LIMIT 1
    ];

    List<Opportunity> records = new List<Opportunity>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations() + 1; i++)
    {
        Opportunity record = new Opportunity(/*required fields*/);
        record.Web_Sources__c = 'A';
        record.StageName = isWonStage;
        records.add(record);
    }
    insert records;

    for (Opportunity record : records) record.Web_Sources__c = 'B';
    Test.startTest();
        update record;
        Integer emailInvocations = Limits.getEmailInvocations();
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, emailInvocations,
        'Email invocations should be grouped to save on governor limits');
}
```

**This test will fail! Your code is not properly bulkified.** I will leave fixing that gap in the code as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score -2):

Its very simple

Create  one test class and method

Create one opportunity record and then update same record.
While updating make sure "IsWon" field should be true and value of "Web_Sources__c" field while updating should not be matched with value of that field while inserting

Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: I did create a test class with one method, I inserted the fields that are necessary for the test to run and no luck. In my test class I need to compare old values and the new values of a field. Because thats what my trigger does.

Comment: @Alias311 Keep in mind your Trigger operates on Update, so you'd need to insert a record and then perform an Update operation on it.